# Ho to layout with flexbox with angular's isolated css

Tags: angular, flexbox

Given following sample html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset=" utf-8 ">
    <title>AngularFlex</title>
    <meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ">
</head>

<body style="display: flex;">
    <div style="background: red; height: 100px; flex:1 "></div>
    <div style="background: green; height: 100px; flex:2 "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**
[image: Wanted layout without angular]

Now I want to achieve this layout with Angular and multiple components. Following  html is generated by angular:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularFlex</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body style="display: flex;">
    <app-root>
        <app-component1>
            <div style="background: red; height: 100px; width: 100px; flex:1"></div>
        </app-component1>
        <app-component2>
            <div style="background: green; height: 100px; width: 100px; flex:2"></div>
        </app-component2>
    </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

**Result:**
[image: Broken layout in angular]

As you can see, the layout is broken since angular adds an extra html node for each component and is isolating the component's CSS.

I know there are different approaches to solve this problem:

1. Use global style and add CSS to the angular-generated html nodes
2. Use the :host selector in any child component to style the generated node

However, I was wondering which is really the best practice for big projects? How to use flexbox from scratch in Angluar without pain?

Comment: There's https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki to help you. It makes flex easier in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Common Practice**

To be able to use flex layout seamlessly with components you can use the `:host`-selector.
`:host` allows you to apply a style directly to the component element.

```
/* app.component1.scss */
:host {
  /* <app-component1> becomes a flex container */
  display: flex;
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

**Global Styles**

If you like to reuse styles in different child components you can think about using *mixins*.
Just provide a *mixin* globally and import it into the component's style file.
This makes your style reusable and you don't loose the benefit of `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`.